# change values in dataframe by lookup matrix/df

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(rank = c('R1', 'R2', 'R3' ), cat = c(1, 2, 2))
```

> ```
> rank cat
> 1   R1   1
> 2   R2   2
> 3   R3   2
> ```

and then a mapping table, which I store as a matrix (but it could be another format too)

```
mapping <- matrix(c('A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'D'), nrow=3, ncol=2) 
rownames(mapping) <- c('R1', 'R2', 'R3')
colnames(mapping) <- c(1, 2)

   1   2  
R1 "A" "C"
R2 "A" "B"
R3 "A" "D"
```

so, I want the df to refer to the mapping with an output, e.g.

```
rank == R1 and cat == 1: out == A
```

Usually I spread the row-column pairs and merge this to the original df, but in this case the mapping table is quite large (dim = 8x8) in reality. So, I am unable to think of a solution. I also tried chaining multiple if-else (small sample below),

```
if (df$rank == 'R1' & df$cat == 1) {
  df$out<- 'A'
  } else if(df$rank == 'R2' & df$cat == 2) {
    df$out <- 'C'
  } else {
      df$out<- 'X'
      }
```

but this becomes also too complex (and gives errors).

How do I achieve replacing values in the df from a mapping table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option would be to `melt` the `matrix` and do a join

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
left_join(df, melt(mapping), by = c("rank" = "Var1", "cat" = "Var2"))
```

Comment: this works, but I observe that if I don't give names to the matrix and melt it the join doesn't work e.g. mapping <- matrix(c('A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'B'), nrow=3, ncol=2) ;
left_join(df, melt(mapping), by = c("rank" = "Var1", "cat" = "Var2"))
I get:  Can't join on 'Var1' x 'rank' because of incompatible types (integer / factor)

Comment: @Kay Yes, I assume that you had dimnames from the example.  If it doesn't have, you can create one `dimnames <- list(rnames, cnames)`

Comment: while giving names to the columns and rows, makes your code work perfectly

Comment: Without  rownames/columnname,s it gives the deafult row_number/column_number index as two columns `matrix(1:9, 3, 3) %>% melt`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(rank = c('R1', 'R2', 'R3' ), cat = c(1, 2, 2))
mapping <- data.frame(rank = c('R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R1', 'R2', 'R3'), 
                      cat = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
                      mapped = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'D'))
df %>% 
  left_join(mapping)
```

Regards
Paweł

Comment: This is not right. That is not how the objects are structured

Comment: also this is similar to how I do always and for a 8x8 matrix this will become huge

Comment: @Kay: in each case you will end up with such a matrix - if you do the melt from akrun solution, the size will be the same.

Comment: @Sotos: I just wanted to show join structure - it was mentioned in the question, that mapping data can be in other format.